# Need help in rewriting the query using CASE statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
SELECT distinct 
    ID, 
    LOWER(IFF(REGEXP_COUNT(pos_id, '^[0-9]+$')= 1, NULL, pos_id)) as pos 
FROM table1
WHERE date='2022-02-02'
    AND pos_id is not null
    AND id='12345';
```

When I run the above query, I'm getting results like

| ID | POS |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 894f4bb2597f |

But when I run the query below where I have used CASE, I'm getting NULL values as well as NOT NULL values.

```
SELECT distinct 
    ID, 
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(pos_id, '^[0-9]+$')= 1 AND pos_id IS NOT NULL THEN NULL ELSE pos_id
    END as pos 
FROM table1
WHERE date='2022-02-02'
    AND pos_id is not null
    AND id='12345';
```

| ID | POS |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 894f4bb2597f |
| 12345 | NULL |

For one ID, I'm getting NULL as well not NULL values.

I need to remove `pos_id is not null` in the WHERE clause and add that in CASE statement.

How to rewrite this query using CASE statement by removing the condition - `pos_id is not null` from the WHERE clause?

I tried the below query using CASE statement but not getting the correct results:

```
SELECT distinct 
    ID,
    CASE when REGEXP_COUNT(pos_id,'^[0-9]+$')=1 and 
       pos_id is not null  
                 THEN null else pos_id end
FROM table1
WHERE date='2022-02-02';
```

When I use CASE, I'm getting the count as 1,455,345 ROWS
but when I use - `LOWER(IFF(REGEXP_COUNT(pos_id, '^[0-9]+$')= 1, NULL, pos_id`
I'm getting COUNT as 2768 rows

Comment: Sample data will help your question.

Comment: When I use CASE, I'm getting the count as 1,455,345 ROWS
   but when I use - LOWER(IFF(REGEXP_COUNT(pos_id, '^[0-9]+$')= 1, NULL, pos_id
   I'm getting COUNT as 2768 rows

Comment: Kindly guide me on this

Comment: Your first query used LOWER function, but the result returned "894F4BB2597F" which contained UPPER cases, something is not right here. Again, if you can share some sample data, it can help us to see what the issue is.

Comment: That's a typing mistake..

Comment: It's so difficult to figure out what is going on without any sample data. Can you add pos_id as one of the columns to be selected so you would have id, pos_id and pos in your result set. Also, to test, you can try the iff function as well as the case statement in the same query, then find some examples where you get different results for each of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the key point of you question is the final sentence:

> When I use CASE, I'm getting the count as 1,455,345 ROWS but when I use - LOWER(IFF(REGEXP_COUNT(pos_id, '^[0-9]+$')= 1, NULL, pos_id I'm getting COUNT as 2768 rows

So take your SQL and pushing it together with some input trying to understand "why the results are different" etc etc.

And really you are asking why do I how more distinct values when I don't to lower then then when I do.

The point is case sensitive counts will always be same or great than case insensitive counts.

```
SELECT 
    column2 as pos_id,
    LOWER(IFF(REGEXP_COUNT(pos_id, '^[0-9]+$')= 1, NULL, pos_id)) as pos_i, 
    CASE 
        WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(pos_id, '^[0-9]+$') = 1 AND pos_id IS NOT NULL THEN NULL 
        ELSE pos_id
    END as pos_c
    ,lower(pos_c) as lower_pos_c
    ,count(distinct pos_i) over() as IFF_rows_count
    ,count(distinct pos_c) over() as CASE_rows_count
    ,count(distinct lower_pos_c) over() as LOWER_CASE_rows_count
FROM VALUES
    (12345, '894f4bb2597f'),
    (12346, '1234'),
    (12346, null),
    (123, 'aaa'),
    (123, 'Aaa'),
    (123, 'aAa'),
    (123, 'aaA');
```

| POS_ID | POS_I | POS_C | LOWER_POS_C | IFF_ROWS_COUNT | CASE_ROWS_COUNT | LOWER_CASE_ROWS_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 894f4bb2597f | 894f4bb2597f | 894f4bb2597f | 894f4bb2597f | 2 | 5 | 2 |
| 1234 | null | null | null | 2 | 5 | 2 |
| null | null | null | null | 2 | 5 | 2 |
| aaa | aaa | aaa | aaa | 2 | 5 | 2 |
| Aaa | aaa | Aaa | aaa | 2 | 5 | 2 |
| aAa | aaa | aAa | aaa | 2 | 5 | 2 |
| aaA | aaa | aaA | aaa | 2 | 5 | 2 |